# Server responds with a 403 error after browser update

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome, mozilla, http-status-code-403

I have a site that plays music. The user can listen to a song only by navigating to a specific site on the server that retrieves the music file and presents it to the user through the audio html tag. In order to prevent the users from accessing directly the song's address I implemented a year ago the following  htaccess script:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://myexamplesite.000webhostapp.com/"

ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(myexamplesite\.)?000webhostapp [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(myexamplesite\.)?000webhostapp.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(mp3|png|jpg)$ - [F]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www.)?(myexamplesite.000webhostapp.com)(/)?.*$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*.(.zip|.rar|.exe|.mp3|.pdf|.swf|.psd)$ http://myexamplesite.000webhostapp.com/error404.php [R,NC]
```

This script has been working flawlessly until a week ago, when chrome and mozilla updated and since then I see the error below on the chrome developer tools.
The browser cannot load any media such as images, documents and music files as described in the script above.

[image]
When I remove the script the problem is resolved but by doing so lets the users access and hotlink my resources with great ease.

The most confusing part is that mobile browsers have not any problem while desktop ones show errors. For example the updated chrome and firefox mobile browsers can access the site normally with all those resources without the issues dealt on desktop browsers.

I have tested if the problem appears in various computers and it still appears.
I believe that the problem shows up in newly updated browsers because the problem does not show up on elder versions of mozilla firefox desktop browser (version 47).

What causes this problem? How can I deal with it? I need a solution that does not override the main purpose of the htaccess script; to not allow direct access and hotlinking to sensitive media (images, pdf documents and mp3 files).